# Windbg `!uniqstack` command fails on specific version

Tags: sdk, windows-10, windbg

I have a dump file which loads just fine on most versions of Windbg I have access to. But on the specific Windbg version from Windows 10 SDK -- v10.0.15063.137, my `!uniqstack` command spits out the following error for *every* thread with an unique callstack:

```
Requested number of stack frames (0xfffffff87dceaa87) is too large! The 
maximum number is 0xffff.
                 ^ Range error in '~.;k -782315579'
```

Its the same error for every thread.  However `~*kv` works just fine.

Is this a bug? If so, I can't find any forum to report it to. Microsoft's Connect website doesn't make it clear where these kind of bugs belong.

Comment: I also have issues with latest Windbg from Creators Update SDK. Use older one (RS1 or TH2), here it don't have issues.

Comment: there is an update of SDK/Windbg to version 15063.400, maybe it fixes your issue.